# How to pass parameter to a codigniter function from cron job?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I am using `codeigniter` framework. I am trying to pass a parameter to a function from corn tab. Below I have posted my code and cron command.

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        $this->home(); //shows the home function
    }

    public function my_test($parameter)
    {
      //do something here using $parameter;
    }
 }
```

cron job command

```
10 5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/myproject/index.php 'test/my_test/2'
```

Please tell me what wrong I have done.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use the `wget` with cronjobs

wget http://example.com/index.php/controller/method/paramValue

I was having the same issue then converted it to use the wget

I know you want to know what is wrong but I hope this can help :)